# new to ubuntu installed flatpak and im getting this error when im updating

Tags: apt, updates

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources (*PPA = Personal Package Archive*) so all security is on you to perform as no guarantees of quality/fitness etc. is provided.  A quick check of https://launchpad.net/~flatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable should have shown you it didn't provide support for *kinetic* (22.10), thus adding it was an incorrect/unwise decision.

Comment: The *duplicate* answer deals with your error message & mistake in adding the PPA;  the excellent answer from @Archisman Panigrahi outlines both how to fix for your situation & what you should have done.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a PPA to install Flatpak in Ubuntu 22.10, because it is already there in the default repositories. You got this error message because the PPA does not have a package for your version of Ubuntu.

First, remove the PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:flatpak/stable
```

Then, update the APT index.

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, install flatpak with

```
sudo apt install flatpak
```